# Retain Checkbox values in Yii gridview pagination

Tags: php, ajax, pagination, yii

I have a gridview which contains a checkbox column and also uses pagination. When I check some checkboxes in the first page and navigate to the second page and check another one in the second page, the options I checked in the first page is not retained there. Is it posssible to retain the checkbox values during pagination?

**Code for Gridview is**

```
$widget = $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'     => $model->search(),
    'cssFile'          => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/media/js/admin/css/admingridview.css',
    //'filter' => $model,
    'ajaxUpdate'       => true,
    'enablePagination' => true,
    'columns'          => array(
        array(
            'name'   => 'id',
            'header' => '#',
            'value'  => '$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)',
        ),
        array(
            'class'          => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'selectableRows' => '2',
            'header' => 'Selected',
        ),
        array(
            'name'   => 'fb_user_id',
            'header' => 'FaceBook Id',
            'value'  => 'CHtml::encode($data->fb_user_id)',
        ),
        array(
            'name'   => 'first_name',
            'header' => 'Name',
            'value'  => 'CHtml::encode($data->first_name)',
        ),
        array(
            'name'   => 'email_id',
            'header' => 'Email',
            'value'  => 'CHtml::encode($data->email_id)',
        ),
        array(
            'name'   => 'demo',
            'type'   => 'raw',
            'header' => "Select",
            'value'  => 'CHtml::checkBox("email[]","",array("class"=>"check","value"=>$data->email_id))',
        ),
    ),
));
```

**Edit:**

Extension for remembering the selected options in gridview,check this link [Selgridview](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/selgridview)

Thanks to ***[bool.dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720508/bool-dev)***

Comment: are your checkboxes coming for all the rows? i mean why didn't you go for CCheckBoxColumn?

Comment: @bool.dev I used CCheckBoxColumn,but it also not useful for this

Comment: aside for the fact that you want retention of checkbox state, are you fine with using ccheckboxcolumn? i mean other than checkbox state, can you do everything else that you are doing with ccheckboxcolumn?

Comment: @bool.dev i just add ccheckboxcolumn and all the other working normal only pblm is with the checkbox value retaination .i didn't find in any sites which developed like this

Comment: ok..can you add the CCheckBoxColumn version to your question? only add the modified part, also leave the old code as is.

Comment: yes i added the ccheckboxcolumn to my code..

Comment: i'm working on a solution for this, lemme see

Comment: @bool.dev That's great...ok try ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use sessions/cookies to store the checked values. I'm not very sure how to make cookies work, so i'll tell you how to do it with sessions. Specifically the user session that yii creates.

Now to use sessions we need to pass the checked (and unchecked) ids to the controller, therefore we'll modify the data being sent to the controller on every ajax update(i.e between paginations), to do this we exploit the `beforeAjaxUpdate` option of [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#beforeAjaxUpdate-detail).

I'm also using [CCheckBoxColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCheckBoxColumn) **instead** of the following in your code(of course you can modify the solution to suit your own needs):

```
array(
     'name' => 'demo',
     'type'=>'raw',
     'header' => "Select",
     'value' => 'CHtml::checkBox("email[]","",array("class"=>"check","value"=>$data->email_id))',
),
```

#### GridView Changes:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    // added id of grid-view for use with $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked(containerID,columnID)
    'id'=>'first-grid',

    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'cssFile' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/media/js/admin/css/admingridview.css',

    // added this piece of code
    'beforeAjaxUpdate'=>'function(id,options){options.data={checkedIds:$.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("first-grid","someChecks").toString(),
        uncheckedIds:getUncheckeds()};
        return true;}',

    'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
    'enablePagination' => true,
    'columns' => array(
            array(
                 'name' => 'id',
                 'header' => '#',
                 'value' => '$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)',
            ),
            array(
                 'name' => 'fb_user_id',
                 'header' => 'FaceBook Id',
                 'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->fb_user_id)',
            ),
            array(
                 'name' => 'first_name',
                 'header' => 'Name',
                 'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->first_name)',
            ),
            array(
                 'name' => 'email_id',
                 'header' => 'Email',
                 'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->email_id)',
            ),

            /* replaced the following with CCheckBoxColumn
              array(
                 'name' => 'demo',
                 'type'=>'raw',
                 'header' => "Select",
                 'value' =>'CHtml::checkBox("email[]","",array("class"=>"check","value"=>$data->email_id))',
              ),
            */

            array(
                 'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
                 'selectableRows' => '2',
                 'header'=>'Selected',
                 'id'=>'someChecks', // need this id for use with $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked(containerID,columnID)
                 'checked'=>'Yii::app()->user->getState($data->email_id)', // we are using the user session variable to store the checked row values, also considering here that email_ids are unique for your app, it would be best to use any field that is unique in the table
            ),
    ),
));
?>
```

Pay special attention to the code for `beforeAjaxUpdate` and CCheckBoxColumn, in beforeAjaxUpdate we are passing `checkedIds` as a csv string of all the ids(in this case email_ids) that have been checked and `uncheckedIds` as a csv string of all the unchecked ids, we get the unchecked boxes by calling a function `getUncheckeds()`, which follows shortly. Please take note here, that when i was testing i had used an integer id field (of my table) as the unique field, and not an email field.

The `getUncheckeds()` function can be registered like this anywhere in the view file for gridview:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('getUnchecked', "
       function getUncheckeds(){
            var unch = [];
            /*corrected typo: $('[name^=someChec]') => $('[name^=someChecks]') */
            $('[name^=someChecks]').not(':checked,[name$=all]').each(function(){unch.push($(this).val());});
            return unch.toString();
       }
       "
);
```

In the above function pay attention to the selectors and `each` and `push` function.

With that done, we need to modify the controller/action for this view.

```
public function actionShowGrid(){
     // some code already existing
     // additional code follows
     if(isset($_GET['checkedIds'])){
          $chkArray=explode(",", $_GET['checkedIds']);
          foreach ($chkArray as $arow){
               Yii::app()->user->setState($arow,1);
          }
     }
     if(isset($_GET['uncheckedIds'])){
          $unchkArray=explode(",", $_GET['uncheckedIds']);
          foreach ($unchkArray as $arownon){
               Yii::app()->user->setState($arownon,0);
          }
     }
     // rest of the code namely render()
}
```

That's it, it should work now.

Comment: thanks a lot..will check it ...thanks for ur patience to figure out the solution..

Comment: you are welcome, next time give a bounty on such huge questions :). I did say, i'll try, so i did. Anyway, remember the main points, **sessions/cookies** , **beforeAjaxUpdate**, and the `setState()` `getState()` functions. You can store things in separate session variable instead of the user session, if you wish.

Comment: also, in addition to `isset` you might also want to check for `empty`

Comment: Sure...Thanks for ur huge support.

Comment: there's also an extension that i came across today, which might be of help: [selgridview](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/selgridview)

Comment: @MrFaisal have left comment in your question with hints

Answer (score 1):

For developing that scheme you would need to know working of what happens when you navigate.

When ever you navigate to a pagination page ajax calls are made and new data is received and it is fetched from CActive Record or what ever the data source. New data is in accordance of database records or source records. when you come back to previous page again Ajax call is made and content is updated so same comes as it is in database.

what i feel is you should save data of checked items temporary and make it permanent if action is made.

You can do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    var thisCheck = $(this);
    if (thisCheck.is (':checked')){
        // do what you want here, the way to access the text is using the
        // $(this) selector. The following code would output pop up message with
        // the selected checkbox text
        $(this).val());
    }
});
</script>
```

you can save temporary storage somewhere

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..Can u provide any example?

Comment: id you checkbox a database field or not?

Answer (score 0):

**Also make this work on normal form submit:**

I wanted to add this as a comment on bool.dev's answer, but I do not have enough reputation to do that yet. So I had to put it in a separate answer.

bool.dev, your answer is great and it works well, thanx.

However, as intended, it only works when ajax calls update the gridview. I have the gridview forming part of a form, so I wanted it to also work on normal submission of the form, otherwise the checkboxes are not loaded again when there are other validation errors on the form.

So, in ADDITION to what you did, I added hidden fields on my form e.g.:

```
<input type="hidden" name='checkedBox1' id='checkedBox1' value=''>
<input type="hidden" name='uncheckedBox1' id='uncheckedBox1' value=''>
```

Then, before submitting the form, my sumbit button runs your getChecked() and getUncheckeds() functions and store their results in the hidden fields:

```
if ($('#checkedBox1').length >0)   {$('[name=checkedBox1]').val(getChecked());}
if ($('#uncheckedBox1').length >0) {$('[name=uncheckedBox1]').val(getUncheckeds());}
```

In the controller, besides from checking for $_GET['checkedIds'], you also check for $_POST['checkedBox1'] and store its values to session in the same way you do for $_GET['checkedIds'], using the same session variable.

Do the same with $_POST['uncheckedBox1'].

That should work.