# Yii2- How to retain checkbox column checked columns with pagination

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, gridview, yii2

I have a `gridview` with check boxes with `pagination`. I have set the pagination to `5`. By default all the values are checked. If record exceeds to `6` then the 6th record is on the next page. Now if I check any values from page 1 and then move to page 2 then on next step only those values are retained which are on page 2.

How can I retain the checkbox values while using pagination?

**Grid View**

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
 <?= GridView::widget([
         'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
          /*'filterModel' => $searchModel,*/
          'id'=>'gv',

          'columns' => [
              ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
         ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => function($d) {
             return ['value' => $d['meter_id']];
         }],

         'Meter_Serial_Number',
         'Meter_Type',
         'Sub_Division_Code',
         'Sub_Division_Name',

       ],
]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

I also have a `ajax` call in my `JS`

```
$('#myid').on('click',function(e) {

e.preventDefault();    
 var strValue = "";        
    $('input[name="selection[]"]:checked').each(function() {

    if(strValue!="")
        {
        strValue = strValue + " , " + this.value;

        }
    else 
       strValue = this.value;     

});
    //alert(strValue);
$.ajax({
     url: '$url',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {data:strValue},         
     success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
     },
  });
});
```

For solution I have checked this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099867/retain-checkbox-values-in-yii-gridview-pagination?answertab=active#tab-top) but the solution doesn't seems to solve my case as it is using `CGridview`

How can I retain the values with pagination?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Based on your case you can choose a way! For example you can save checked IDs on browser storage and read them on other pages, or you can send selected IDs with query string on URL, or you can save them on DB with draft flag. I think there is no straight way in Yii2 to solve this.

Comment: @meysam can you please provide me any sample code for this ?

Comment: @MrFaisal, commenting as you asked me specifically in the related question. I have not worked on Yii for a long time, so I am not up to date, but a quick review of the Yii2 docs have revealed that now ajax functionality is done through **[pjax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pjax)**. So all that you have to do is modify the old solution from related question/answer to fit into the pjax method. The base concept will be the same, i.e store the checked ids in `session`. Pjax also uses push state, so you might be able to use that instead of session. Good luck exploring!